# Qual a vantagem em se utilizar Angular Deferred Loading em comparação com *ngIf?

Tags: angular

Foi anunciado que a versão 17 do Angular conterá uma nova solução para carregamento em demandas nos componentes, chamado **Deferred Loading**.

Quais seriam as vantagens de se utilizar o `defer` em comparação com a antiga diretiva `*ngIf`?

Deferred Loading:

```
{#defer when condition}
  <app-my-component />
{/defer}
```

Diretiva ngIf:

```
<app-my-component *ngIf="condition"> </app-my-acomponent>
```

Comment: Andei lendo alguns artigos no Medium sobre e a grande vantagem é que o **#defer** possui 2 tipos de sentenças de condições o **`when`** e o **`on`**, que inclusive podem ser utilizados juntos, dando um maior poder e controle quanto a renderização dos elementos no template de uma forma tardia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A principal vantagem é **otimizar o tamanho do bundle** inicial da sua aplicação, isso já acontecia quando usamos *lazy loading* nas rotas, você pode perceber que ao entrar em uma rota usando *lazy loading* o navegador irá carregar aquela parte de javascript somente quando for a hora, essa possibilidade se amplia com o `@defer`, e ai está a maior diferença, antes usando apenas uma condição `*ngIf` o seu componente ainda sim iria fazer parte do *bundle*.

Além disso, com defer você possui maior controle do seu template, pois só será carregado o conteúdo quando um gatilho for disparado, o framework oferece vários gatilhos já prontos: *on idle, on viewport, on interaction, on hover, on immediate, on timer*:

```
@defer (on hover) {
  <app-my-component></app-my-component>
}
```

Mas você também pode criar o seu customizado usando *when*:

```
@defer (when condicaoBollean) {
    <app-my-component></app-my-component>
}
```

Junto ao `@defer`, você pode usar também algumas condições especiais como `@placeholder`, `@loading`, `@error`, esse blocos especiais ajudam a você dar um feedback adequado enquando a condição e o carregamento não forem concluídos.